# Write event using set-theoretic operations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Two series of n throws of a dice in each are carried out. 
Let $A_{ijk}$ denotes the event when in $i$ series $i\in\{1, 2\}$ on the $j$ throw $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ a number $k$ fell on the dice $k\in\{1,\dots,6\}$.
I need to write the event using set-theoretic operations and $A_{ijk}$ when in each series at least one $1$ and at least one $6$ was felt on a dice.

My answer is:
$$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2}\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}\bigcap_{k=2}^{5}A_{ijk}\right)^C$$
Is it correct?

Comment: You have written the event that at least one 1 OR one 6 appeared.

Comment: I like the question but I don't get the grammar here, could you rephrase that?

Comment: "in each series *i* there is at least one throw *j* with outcome 1 and at least one throw *j'* with outcome 6":
$$\forall i \exists j\exists j'(A_{ij1}\land A_{ij'6}) \leftrightarrow \bigcap_{i}\bigcup_{j}\bigcup_{j'}(A_{ij1}\cap A_{ij'6})$$